# Interpretation of for loop.

Tags: programming-languages

> for every j != i in {0,....,n-1}

How to interpret this for loop? I never seen this type of definition of for loop.

Is it like -  **`j=0 to n-1; j !=i ; ++j`**

Comment: It's pseudocode, isn't it? I suppose just take it literally then?

Comment: If `i` is not defined before the meaning is clearly $for\;(i,j)\;\in\{(a,b) \mid a \in \{0..n-1\} \land b \in \{0,..n-1\} \land a\neq b\}$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the probable interpretation:

> for every $j \neq i$ in $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$:
>
> code

should be interpreted as:

> for every $j$ in $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$:
>
> if $j \neq i$:
>
> code

This is similar to the way this kind of statement is interpreted in mathematical text.

It is also possible that the roles of $i$ and $j$ should be switched — this should be clear from context, and it's an ambiguity that also exists in mathematical texts.

As mentioned in Evil's answer, if neither $i$ nor $j$ has been defined, then the interpretation is probably

> for every $i,j$ in $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$:
>
> if $i \neq j$:
>
> code

Comment: Upvoted, but note that "for every i, j in {0,…,n−1}" isn't 100% formal either. I think Evil's formulation of that possibility (as two nested loops) is clearer.

Comment: Evil's interpretation is a guess - perhaps the loops should be switched?

Comment: Swapping the order of the inner `i` and outer `j` loops has no effect on the semantics of the program. (However, one or the other ordering may well take more advantage of *cache effects* if we're going to use the loop indices as indices into a 2D array. See [Row-major and column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).)

Answer (score 13):

There is another interpretation, both $i, j$ might be variables, in that case it is double loop:

> for every $j$ in $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$:
>
> for every $i$ in $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$:
>
> if $j \neq i$:
>
> code

Simply reading it out loud helps only if we know beforehand if $i$ is fixed variable or another counter, so there is context missing.

Comment: An analogous mathematical notation would be $$\sum_{i,j=0\\i\neq j}^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 6):

Just read it out loud. "For every $j$ that is not equal to $i$, in $\{0, \dots, n-1\}$."

In my opinion, it would be better to have written "For every $j\in\{0, \dots, n-1\}\setminus\{i\}$."

Comment: My guess is that $i$ is a counter, too.